# using python 3.6.2 as an interpreter in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I am trying to set up Eclipse Oxygen with PyDev with Python 3.6.2 as the interpreter. I can't seem to install Python 3.6.2 (or Python 2.x for that matter) as Eclipse cannot find the pip executable file. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling Python 3.6.2 but it still doesn't work.

When I select the folder to be added to the system python path I get a message in the packages tab saying `'Unable to find pip executable. Searched in: /usr/local/bin`

[image]

Does anybody have an idea of what I can do to make it work?

Thanks

Comment: First of all - copy your error into the question. It's no good having it as a screenshot as this wont come up on google for anyone looking for help in the future. Secondly - what is returned by the command 'which pip' and 'pip -V' on your machine? -- Include them in your question, not as a comment

Comment: In my Terminal, after opening python3, if I type 'which pip' i get a syntax error and if i type 'pip -V' i get a name error... I presume that i have not managed to to what you have suggested?

Comment: Dont open up Python, just run it on the commandline `which pip` and `pip -V`

Comment: nothing is returned for 'which pip' and I get 'command not found' for 'pip -V'

Comment: Have you tried the quick auto-config? The above errors explain why Eclipse cannot find the executable.. pip is not installed on your machine with an executable in `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Yes, I have tried both the quick auto-config and the advanced auto-config which gives me options of /usr/bin/python, /usr/bin/python2.6, /usr/bin/python2.7, (I have a mac so python 2.x is already installed) /usr/local/bin/python3 and /usr/local/bin/python3.6 - all of which have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem in PyDev not finding pip depending on some peculiarities of your install, but note that everything should still work except you won't be able to install packages from within PyDev (you still can do it from the command line).

This has also been reported at: https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/853

So, please wait for the next release where this should be improved (but as I said, everything else should work as usual and you don't really need to worry much about it, the only thing is that you'll have to use pip from the command line, not from within PyDev).

Comment: I think that PyDev is indeed looking in the correct file as it says 'Unable to find pip executable. Searched in: /usr/local/bin' which isn't the problem reported above. I have looked in that file and there are two aliases named 'pip3' and 'pip3.6' that link to '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3' and '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip3.6' respectively. As a hack, if i rename one of them 'pip' then PyDev finds it. If i then click on 'Install/Uninstall with pip' i am asked to enter a command to execute with 'install <package>' as default.Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, renaming (or creating a link) does work, but then if you have more than one Python installed, things may become blurry (because each should have its own pip executable) -- the solution is pydev doing `python -m pip` instead of looking for an executable.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how do i get PyDev to do 'python -m pip'? cheers

Comment: Right now, you have to wait for the next release (I have to do that on PyDev itself https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/853 is tracking that... as this is somewhat critical I plan to do it soon -- meaning having a release with that fix within at most the next 4 weeks).